# Cocos2d-x Launching a URL on Android

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

i want to open URL from my game that created by cocos2dx 2.2.2 so any help pleaseeee

Comment: Just a FYI, with cocos2d-x 3.4 , there's a system call to open URL. Just use Application::openURL(urlString);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to open browser app, you should use [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) system in Java. To call Java code from C++, you should use [JNI](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html).

You can create method, that open URLs inside cocos2d-x's Java code. It's most simpliest way.

1. Find `org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView` java class (location: *cocos2d/platform/android/java*)
2. Add method to this class

   ```
   public static void openWebURL( String inURL ) {
        if (mCocos2dxGLSurfaceView != null) {
             Intent browse = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW , Uri.parse( inURL ) );
             browse.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
             mCocos2dxGLSurfaceView.getContext().startActivity( browse );
        }
   }
   ```
3. Include `JniHelper` in C++ source file

   ```
   #if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_ANDROID)
   #include "JniHelper.h"
   #endif
   ```
4. Add code, that calls Java method into right place

   ```
   #if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_ANDROID)
   JniMethodInfo t;
   if (JniHelper::getStaticMethodInfo(t,
           "org/cocos2dx/lib/Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView",
           "openWebURL",
           "(Ljava/lang/String;)V")) {
       jstring stringArg = t.env->NewStringUTF(yourWebUrl);
       t.env->CallStaticIntMethod(t.classID, t.methodID, stringArg);
       t.env->DeleteLocalRef(stringArg1);
       t.env->DeleteLocalRef(t.classID);
   }
   #endif
   ```

More correct way is to define Java method in your basic [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) class (that extends `Cocos2dxActivity`). You should handle application lifecycle to store correct static reference to your activity in Java code, or store local reference to activity object in C++ code.

Comment: thanx very much this also worked with me http://cocos2d-x.org/forums/6/topics/11290